# Why is my Beautiful Soup loop returning nothing when scraping content with '_ngcontent'?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, ng-content

How can I scrap a text included in a "_ngcontent" frontend?

Here is the code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs
import requests

url = 'https://formosodoaraguaia.megasofttransparencia.com.br/receitas-e-despesas/empenho?faseDoEmpenho=4&etapaDaDespesa=4&dataInicial=01%2F01%2F2019'
page_to_scrap = requests.get(url)
soup = bs (page_to_scrap.text, 'html.parser')


data = soup.findAll("label _ngcontent-lpf-c7", attrs={"class":"valor"})

for i in data:
  print (data.text)
```

**The loop returns nothing**, as if there is no content in the selector I choosed.

Does it have something to do with the content being in a pop-up page? How can I scrap something like this?

Thank you all!

Update -------------------------------------------------------------

The "_ngcontent" id changes when I reload the page. This is how it looks right now:
[image]

Comment: there is no such tag `label _ngcontent-lpf-c7` on the page. can you add the screenshot of the elements you're trying to extract

Comment: That's because the text keeps changing (I've noticed it aftewards).  Adding the photo right now.

Answer (score 0):

If you open the page source you will see only this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Portal Transparencia</title>
    <base href="/">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="./assets/favicon/favicon.ico">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="16x16" href="./assets/favicon/favicon-16x16.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="32x32" href="./assets/favicon/favicon-32x32.png">
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="96x96" href="./assets/favicon/favicon-96x96.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="57x57" href="./assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-57x57.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="60x60" href="./assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-60x60.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="72x72" href="./assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-72x72.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="76x76" href="./assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-76x76.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="114x114" href="./assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-114x114.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="120x120" href="./assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-120x120.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="144x144" href="./assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-144x144.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="./assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-152x152.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="./assets/favicon/apple-touch-icon-180x180.png">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.f7136d10368295392983.css">
</head>

<body>
    <mega-root></mega-root>
    <script src="runtime-es2015.b45dbb8b28e64d8d5234.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="runtime-es5.b45dbb8b28e64d8d5234.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es5.06416a6230f9503a933a.js" nomodule defer></script>
    <script src="polyfills-es2015.fb891162ab77d6e3ed02.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es2015.a978096e6e6cd72c87b2.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="main-es5.a978096e6e6cd72c87b2.js" nomodule defer></script>
</body>

</html>
```

No divs, no spans, no classes. That's all you get with `requests`. That's because all the content is loaded dynamically via JavaScript modules afterwards.

To get the dynamic content, you'll need a library that uses headless browser (a browser that has no GUI). The most popular ones for this purpose, which also support Python, are [Selenium](https://www.selenium.dev), [Pyppeteer](https://pypi.org/project/pyppeteer/) and [Playwright](https://playwright.dev).